# No route to host for port 6379

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I'm getting a "no route to host" error when I'm connecting a remote server to my Redis instance on another server.

Redis is definitely running and listening on port 6379. I can connect to it locally.

The server with Redis has this configured for `iptables -S`

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N FORWARD_IN_ZONES
-N FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE
-N FORWARD_OUT_ZONES
-N FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-N FORWARD_direct
-N FWDI_public
-N FWDI_public_allow
-N FWDI_public_deny
-N FWDI_public_log
-N FWDO_public
-N FWDO_public_allow
-N FWDO_public_deny
-N FWDO_public_log
-N INPUT_ZONES
-N INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-N INPUT_direct
-N IN_public
-N IN_public_allow
-N IN_public_deny
-N IN_public_log
-N OUTPUT_direct
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_IN_ZONES
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_OUT_ZONES
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
-A FORWARD_IN_ZONES -g FWDI_public
-A FORWARD_OUT_ZONES -g FWDO_public
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_log
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_deny
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_allow
-A FWDI_public -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_log
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_deny
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_allow
-A INPUT_ZONES -g IN_public
-A IN_public -j IN_public_log
-A IN_public -j IN_public_deny
-A IN_public -j IN_public_allow
-A IN_public -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

`netstat -rn` prints out:

```
0.0.0.0         178.xxx.xxx.1   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.10.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
10.136.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth1
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 br-e071bb9e15A
178.xxx.xxx.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

Is there anything misconfigured here, and how can I fix it so that remote servers can connect to port `6379`?

Answer (score 0):

From the chain names, your configuration is using [`firewalld`](https://firewalld.org/) which uses `iptables` as backend and generates `iptables` rules from its own configuration. Redhat provides a lot of [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/sec-Configuring_firewalld.html#sec-Opening_Ports_in_the_firewall-CLI) for its usage. For your case, providing access should be done with:

```
firewall-cmd --add-port=6379/tcp
```

This will probably be reflected like this in the `iptables` rules:

```
# iptables -S -t filter | grep -w 6379
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6379 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

This will grant temporarily access to redis running on the host. If you think you made a mistake, you can revert the configuration with:

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Once fine with the results, you can run again the same comment with the additonal option `--permanent` to write the configuration instead of altering the rules, like this for a permanent setting:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=6379/tcp
```

For later, you always need two commands to alter it permanently: once for the configuration, once for the running firewall (a `firewall-cmd --reload` after a `firewall-cmd --permanent ...` is good enough).

Comment: This solution assumes the redis service is *really* visible on the host, with a socket opened on the host, not only for example just inside Docker.